# How to allow button and swipe to work together using caroufredsel?

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I am using caroufredsel to go to next page and previous page. Now I'm trying to implement swipe to this. but I'm having difficulty. My current code is as below.

```
function carouFredSel() {
    //  Scrolled by user interaction
    $('#pages').carouFredSel({
        prev:{ button: '#prev',
               onBefore: function() { $("#pages").children().children().hide(); },
               onAfter: function() { $("#pages").triggerHandler("currentVisible").children().show(); }
             },
        next:{ button: '#next',
               onAfter: function() { $("#pages").children().children().hide(); $("#pages").triggerHandler("currentVisible").children().show(); getRemainingPages(); }
             },
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        align: 'left',
        auto: false,
        circular: false,
        infinite: true
    });
}
```

How do I allow both swiping and next and previous buttons to work together?

Comment: i'm trying to access this view from mobile. Hence, need the swiping to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration object called 'swipe'.

You can use it this way:

```
      $('#pages').carouFredSel({
        ...
        swipe: {
          onTouch: true
        }
      });
```

You also need this jQuery plugin loaded:
http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/